# How to get Google Test to function properly. Test always fails. (It won't compile)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I got a problem with a unittest in my Google Test application. I want to test if my code produces an exeception if it receives a wrong date or wrong date-format. I used regular expressions with it. I am using Google Test Framework v1.10.0 and TDM GCC (GNU G++ GCC C++ Compiler 9.2.0) and the CodeBlocks IDE 20.03. I am using C++ 11. Using Windows 10.

I get this error when I compile:

```
||=== Build: Debug in GT_wsDB_Record_Class (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\CodeBlocks\GT_Original\GT_wsRecord\GT_wsDB_Record_Class\GT_wsRecord_Test.cpp||In member function 'virtual void wsRecords::wsRecordTest_DoesItThrowExceptionWhenWrongDateIsProvided_Test::TestBody()':|
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\CodeBlocks\GT_Original\GT_wsRecord\GT_wsDB_Record_Class\GT_wsRecord_Test.cpp|28|error: expected ';' before '{' token|
..\..\..\GoogleTest\googletest\googletest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-internal.h|1290|note: in definition of macro 'GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_'|
..\..\..\GoogleTest\googletest\googletest\include\gtest\gtest.h|1970|note: in expansion of macro 'GTEST_TEST_THROW_'|
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\CodeBlocks\GT_Original\GT_wsRecord\GT_wsDB_Record_Class\GT_wsRecord_Test.cpp|28|note: in expansion of macro 'ASSERT_THROW'|
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\CodeBlocks\GT_Original\GT_wsRecord\GT_wsDB_Record_Class\GT_wsRecord_Test.cpp|28|warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]|
..\..\..\GoogleTest\googletest\googletest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-internal.h|1290|note: in definition of macro 'GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_'|
..\..\..\GoogleTest\googletest\googletest\include\gtest\gtest.h|1970|note: in expansion of macro 'GTEST_TEST_THROW_'|
C:\Users\Donald\Documents\CodeBlocks\GT_Original\GT_wsRecord\GT_wsDB_Record_Class\GT_wsRecord_Test.cpp|28|note: in expansion of macro 'ASSERT_THROW'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

I am trying to learn TDD, but I can't seem the test to pass. The productioncode works, it's just the test that doesn't work. I have been working to solve it for 1.5 days already, so trying it this way now.

Hope someone can help me.

Greetings,

Don.

This is the main testfile GT_wsRecord_Test.cpp:

```
/***************************************/
/* wsDB Record Class - UnitTest        */
/* Framework: Google Test v1.10.0      */
/* Author: D. Voogd - Date: 11-06-2020 */
/***************************************/

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "GT_wsRecord.h"
#include <string>    
namespace wsRecords
{
class wsRecordTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:

protected:
    weatherdayRecord wsRecord{"2020-10-03"};
};

TEST_F(wsRecordTest,DoIGetTheRightTimeFromTheConstructor)
{
    std::string wsTime = wsRecordTest::wsRecord.getTime();
    ASSERT_EQ(wsTime,"2020-10-03");
}
TEST_F(wsRecordTest,DoesItThrowExceptionWhenWrongDateIsProvided)
{
    ASSERT_THROW(wsRecord{"2002-20-41"},std::invalid_argument);
}
}
```

This is the definition file GT_wsRecord.h:

```
#ifndef GT_WSRECORD_H_INCLUDED
#define GT_WSRECORD_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

namespace wsRecords
{

class weatherdayRecord
{

public:

// constructor
    weatherdayRecord(std::string time_day);
// destructor
    ~weatherdayRecord();

    // accessors
    std::string getTime() const; // get the time from the day.

    /*
    std::string getWeatherCon() const; // get the weather conditions
    double getMinTemp() const; // get the minimum temperature
    double getMaxTemp() const; // get the maximum temperature
    double getWindSpeed() const; // get the wind speed
    std::string getSymbolVar() const; // get the symbol var for the weather icon
    */

    protected:
    std::string time_day; // date of the day.

    /*
    std::string weather_condition; // weather condition of the day
    double min_temperature; // minimum temperature of the day
    double max_temperature; // maximum temperature of the day
    double wind_speed; // maximum weed speed in meters/sec.
    std::string symbol_var; // symbol that resembles the weather icon
    */
};

}


#endif // GT_WSRECORD_H_INCLUDED
```

And this is implementation file GT_wsRecord.cpp:

```
/***************************************/
/* wsDB Record Class - UnitTest        */
/* Framework: Google Test v1.10.0      */
/* Author: D. Voogd - Date: 11-06-2020 */
/* Implementation                      */
/***************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include "GT_wsRecord.h"
namespace wsRecords{

weatherdayRecord::weatherdayRecord(std::string time_day)
{
 this->time_day = time_day;
}

weatherdayRecord::~weatherdayRecord() {
    ;
}

std::string weatherdayRecord::getTime() const// get the time from the day.
{
    auto const regex = std::regex("((?:19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-([12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])"); // Regex YYYY-MM-DD
    bool const TimeDayContainsRegex = std::regex_search(time_day, regex);
    if(TimeDayContainsRegex == true)
    {
    return time_day;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Wrong date or dateformat.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `wsRecord{"2002-20-41"}` supposed to be doing? `wsRecord` is a data member. Did you mean to do `wsRecord("2002-20-41")` or maybe `weatherdayRecord{"2002-20-41"}`?

Comment: It should create an object instantiated from the class weatherdayRecord with a date datamember time_day. Yes, I tried ASSERT_THROW(wsRecord("2002-20-41"),std::invalid_argument); It gives me an no match for call to '(wsRecords::weatherdayRecord) (const char [11])'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
TEST_F(wsRecordTest,DoIGetTheRightTimeFromTheConstructor)
{
    weatherdayRecord wsRecord{"2020-10-03"};
    std::string wsTime = wsRecord.getTime();
    ASSERT_EQ(wsTime,"2020-10-03");
}
TEST_F(wsRecordTest,DoesItThrowExceptionWhenWrongDateIsProvided)
{
    weatherdayRecord wsRecord{"2020-20-41"};
    ASSERT_THROW(wsRecord.getTime(),std::invalid_argument);
}
```

You want to test that the `getTime()` function throws in the second test, so you first need to create a `weatherdayRecord` with the bad date (which I think you were trying to do in your original code).

Note that there's no need for the `wsRecord` data member. Fixture data members are only necessary when multiple tests need the same object constructed in the same way. In your case you need to construct the `weatherdayRecord` differently for each test.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I wanted to do. I am still a beginner in unittesting... Your code works! Thanks you very much! :)